# removed isc-dhcp-client package caused removal of network manager (ubuntu 18 desktop)

Tags: networking, apt, network-manager, dhcp

I have recently trying to fix some issues that caused me to remove `isc-dhcp-client` package, somehow after i reinstall it, it cant connect to the internet any more.

When i try to open system settings gnome, it somehow fails and when i check network manager, it stated `not found`.

How can i connect to reinstall network manager?

Please advise.

Comment: Apt stores all packages in a local cache. Unless you (unwisely)  cleaned out that cache, then a simple `sudo apt-get install network-manager` should work. If you DID clean out that cache, then use the Search box at the top of the page to learn how to download and install packages to an offline system. There is no secret backdoor to "connect to the network without any networking software." If that command results in an error, then read the error message closely - it contains critical information to help you fix it.

Comment: thanks @user535733, i resolved by using networkd to connect and redownloaded the packages.